# How to reload a div content with Jquery after adding new record to database?

Tags: jquery, yii2

new to Jquery technologies, searched for a solution on how to use ajax to reload a DIV container when new record is added to the database.Just like a live chat.
Please if there is anyone who know how to do it, please I need a guide on how to solve this problem Yii2.

This is my controller code

```
 public function actionMessage($id){

        if(!Yii::$app->getUser()->isGuest){

          // THIS IS INSTANCE OF CHAT FORM
          $model = new Message();
            if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){

             $model->updated_date = date ('Y-m-d H:i:s');
             $model->user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
            //THIS REGISTER MESSAGE COUNT IN DB
             Message::register_changes();
             $model->to = $id;
             $model->save(); 
             return $this->refresh();
            }

         // THIS LOAD THE MODEL OF THE USER
         $models = $this->findModels($id);
        // THIS QUERY THE CHAT MESSAGE FROM THE DB
         $send = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Message::find()->
                orderBy('updated_date ASC'),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 1000000000000,
            ],
        ]);



        // THE IS INSTANT OF USER SEARCH FORM
        $searchModel = new UserlistSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        return $this->render('chating', [
            'models' => $models,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'send' => $send,

            'model'=>$model,

        ]);

    }else{
        return $this->redirect(['site/login']);
    }
}
```

this is my View code

```
<div class="chatbox">             
<div id="chat-board">
<ul>
    <?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $send,
    'summary'=>'',
    'itemOptions' => ['class'=>'item'],
    'itemView' =>'_message',
    ]);?>
</ul>
</div>


    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => $model->formName(),'enableAjaxValidation' => true]); ?>
     <?= $form->field($model, 'message')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder'=> 'Type a message'])->label(false) ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Send'), ['class' => 'btn-send']) ?>
   <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

This is my Javerscript code

```
 <script>
            /* AJAX request to checking for new record */
            function checking(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?=Url::to(['ichat/chating', 'id'=>Yii::$app->request->get('id')])?>',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        counter:$('#chat-board').data('counter')
                    }
                }).done(function( response ) {
                    /* update counter */
                    $('#chat-board').data('counter',response.current);
                    /* check if with response we got a new update */
                    if(response.update==true){
                        $('#chat-board').html(response.message);
                    }
                });
            }
            //Every 20 sec check if there is new update
            setInterval(checking,20000);
        </script>
```

Comment: Youcan user `SetInterval()` for refreshing

Comment: you shouldn't mix php + js -> it's bad practice and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, I will noted that. thank you